# Compiling solidity code with geth+testrpc - Error: Invalid JSON RPC response

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, bug, testrpc, compilation

I'm attempting to compile the following contract using geth console attached to a testrpc instance:

```
contract UnitCounter {
    mapping (address => uint256) public UnitsFrom;
    uint256 public TotalUnits;

    function submitUnits(uint256 Units) {
        UnitsFrom[msg.sender] = Units;
        TotalUnits += Units;
    }
}
```

After running testrpc and connecting:

```
testrpc -a 1000
```

I attached a geth cosole

```
geth attach rpc:http://localhost:8545
```

and did the following:

```
> eth.getCompilers()
["solidity"]
> co=eth.compile.solidity("contract UnitCounter {mapping (address => uint256) public UnitsFrom;uint256 public TotalUnits;function SubmitUnits(uint256 Units) {UnitsFrom[msg.sender] = Units;TotalUnits += Units;}}")
```

Which gives this error:

```
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: {"error":{"code":-32603,"json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type string":"json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type string"},"id":11,"version":"2.0"}
    at web3.js:3119:20
    at web3.js:6023:15
    at web3.js:4995:36
    at <anonymous>:1:4
```

**What does this error mean?
What steps should I take to debug?**

Comment: This smells like geth bug, as JSON-RPC calls should convert everything to JSON before returning. Try use `solc` command line version to compile your contract locally. Here are some examples: https://tokenmarket.net/blog/creating-ethereum-smart-contract-transactions-in-client-side-javascript/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tcpdump` to intercept communication between `geth` and `testrpc`.

This will dump all packets going through loopback interface `lo` from/to port 8545:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -A -i lo port 8545
```

Now you can run `eth.compile.solidity(..)` command in geth console and get JSON-RPC request and response:

**request**

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 14,
  "method": "eth_compileSolidity",
  "params": [
    "contract UnitCounter {mapping (address => uint256) public UnitsFrom;uint256 public TotalUnits;function SubmitUnits(uint256 Units) {UnitsFrom[msg.sender] = Units;TotalUnits += Units;}}"
  ]
}
```

**response**

```
{
  "id": 14,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "error": {
    "message": [
      ":1:1: Warning: Source file does not specify required compiler version!Consider adding \"pragma solidity ^0.4.4\ncontract UnitCounter {mapping (address => uint256) public UnitsFrom;uint256 public TotalUnits;function SubmitUnits(uint256 Units) {UnitsFrom[msg.sender] = Units;TotalUnits += Units;}}\n^-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^\n"
    ],
    "code": -32000
  }
}
```

Form here you can see that:

- actual error is missing `pragma solidity ^0.4.4;` in your code
- `testrpc` returns malformed response (`error.message` must be a string but array is provided, see [JSON-RPC spec](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification))

  - this is [fixed](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc/issues/238) in provider-engine@8.1.18